# Changing nested form partial fields depending on route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby Rails developer student here. I am trying to figure out how to use the same partial form for my create and update methods, but I cannot figure out how to remove the password/password_confirmation fields depending on the route the form is sent to. (I do not want the user to update their password any time they update their other attributes, so I need those fields to dissapear on a route with patch).

Form with all fields below

```
<%= form_for(user, url: users_path) do |form| %>
  <%= form.label 'Name' %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :name%><br>

  <%= form.label 'email' %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :email%><br>

  <%= form.label 'Password' %><br>
  <%= form.password_field :password%><br>

  <%= form.label 'password_confirmation' %><br>
  <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation%><br>

  <%= form.submit (form.object.new_record? ? 'create' : 'update')  %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Hey, just a word of warning about the answer you accepted, that answer will not work if the form gets rerendered with validation errors, so if you for example validate the email adress, and the user submits a valid `:name`, but an invalid `:email`, the expresion `!user.name` will evaluate to false, and therefore your password fields will not show upon rerendering the form. You should use `user.new_record?` instead

Comment: Roland thank you, I did not think about it that way,  although I did end up using  if user.new_record along with adding on: :create to my validated presence for my password, which as far as I can tell should cover it all Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full correct answer code to my question. (changes in bold)

Credit to @roland and @sam for putting me on the right track for this

```
<%= form_for(user, url: users_path) do |form| %>
  <%= form.label 'Name' %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :name%><br>

  <%= form.label 'email' %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :email%><br>

  <%= form.label 'Password' %><br>
  <%= form.password_field :password%><br>

  **<% if form.object.new_record? %>**
      <%= form.label 'password_confirmation' %><br>
      <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation%><br>
  **<% end %>**

  <%= form.submit (form.object.new_record? ? 'create' : 'update')  %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best way, but when I want to use the same form partial with a little difference between the new and edit routes, I check to the see if the value exists for the model. In your case it would look like this.

```
<% if !user.name %>
  <%= form.label 'Password' %><br>
  <%= form.password_field :password%><br>

  <%= form.label 'password_confirmation' %><br>
  <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation%><br>
<% end %>
```

So here, if the user has a name (which they should only have if the record already exists), they won't have the `password` and `password_confirmation` fields, so those won't get passed in the PATCH (update) request.

Comment: I would be careful with this, because if you submit the form and it has validations errors, the user.name will then be defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your question already `form.object.new_record?` checks if the object is a new record or an already saved one. So you can:

```
<% if form.object.new_record? %>
  <%= form.label 'Password' %><br>
  <%= form.password_field :password%><br>
  ...
```

Or you can just use the method directly on the user object:

```
<% if user.new_record? %>
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to create a partial form that only shows up depending on the route path?  For instance all on the same _ partial.html.erb  a form for create/ edit User on a /user path and a form to create/edit Event that shows if the path is /events?  What would that syntax look like?  Maybe if url: users_path ?